# Как разделить вывод элементов списка в цикле в разные ul?

Tags: php

```html
<!--сейчас-->
<ul class="collection__list">
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
</ul>

<!--после разделения-->
<ul class="collection__list">
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="collection__list">
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
  <li class="collection__item"></li>
</ul>
```

```
 $collections=$DB->Query('');
    $max_position=$DB->QueryScalar('SELECT MAX(position) AS max_position FROM collectionslist');
    $count=0;
    $addtxt.='<ul class="collection__list">';
    while ($collection=$DB->GetRow($collections)) {
        $count++;
        if ($collection[1]==null) {
            $max_position++;
            $DB->Query('INSERT INTO collectionslist (id_collection,name, position) VALUES (NULL,\''.str_replace('\'','\\\'',$collection[0]).'\', '.$max_position.');');
            $collection=$DB->QueryRow('SELECT t2.Value,t2.id_collection,t2.name FROM collectionslist AS t2 WHERE name=\''.str_replace('\'','',$collection[0]).'\';');
            if ($collection==null) continue;
        }


            $addtxt.='<li class="collection__item">';
            if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/collection/collection_$collection[1].jpg")) {
                $photo = "collection_" . $collection[1] . ".jpg";
            } else {
                $photo = "no_photo.jpg";
            }
            $addtxt.='<a class="collection__link" href="/collections/'.$collection[1].'/"><img src="/uploads/collection/'.$photo.'"></a>
                        <a class="collection__name" href="/collections/'.$collection[1].'/">'.$collection[2].'</a>

                      </li>';


        if ($count==1) {

            $addtxt.='<li class="collection__item"><a href="/collections/100/"><img src="/uploads/logo_metoyou.png"></a></li>';

        }

    }
  $addtxt.='</ul>';
```

Comment: Вы можете результаты запроса поместить в временный массив и его уже разбивать как вам нужно. Я полагаю в первом ul элементы должны как-то специально сортироваться и их не всегда будет 2. Верно?

Comment: Спасибо я уже решил эту задачу, в моем случае два в первом остальные во втором